# How to show my account page after login in aspx

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to view my account page after `login` in `Textbox` for updating, here is my code

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_SelectUser",con);
        con.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = "SP_SelectUser";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(td.Rows[0]["id"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "");
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        td.Load(dr);
        }
        dr.Close();
        name.Text = td.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
        emailid.Text = td.Rows[0]["emailid"].ToString();
        passwd.Text = td.Rows[0]["Passwd"].ToString();
        mobile.Text = td.Rows[0]["Mobile"].ToString();
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking ? And are you sure this code compile ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this piece of code ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your posted code is still not correct enough to make it clear what exactly your problem is.

For displaying a page from another page, you can use one of these options :

1. Response.Redirect("yourPage.aspx", false);

   OR
2. Server.Transfer("yourPage.aspx", true);

You have to use either of these at the point in your code where you want to change the page from one to another.

Hope this helps.